# Prove that column space = $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix then $\text{col } (A) = \mathbb{R}^m$ iff $\text{rank }  (A) = m$

We prove the first direction.

Assume $\text{col } (A) = \mathbb{R}^m$. Then that means $\text{dim}( \text{col}) A = m$, which means $\text{rank } A = m$

**Other direction:**

Assume $\text{rank } A = m$, then this means $\text{dim } (\text{col } A) = m$ so that means there are $m$ linearly independent vectors in col (A). But how can I claim that it spans $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: It's a consequence of the Steinitz exchange lemma.

Comment: $col(A) \subseteq \mathbb R^m$ and dimension argument

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your vectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then your basis $\{v_1, \cdots, v_m\}$ can be extended to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ by adding more vectors $\{v_{m+1}, \cdots, v_k\}$. However, any set of $k>m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is linearly dependent; a contradiction.